# Image is not rendered in Exoplayer Playerview media3 using setImageDurationMs

Tags: exoplayer, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

Image is not rendered in Exoplayer Playerview

I want to display image as video

I am trying this code

```
val playlist: MutableList<MediaItem> = mutableListOf<MediaItem>()
val mediaItem =   MediaItem.Builder().setImageDurationMs(30000).setUri("content://media/external/images/media/1000005827").build()  playlist.add(mediaItem)
player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
       playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view)
       player.addMediaItems(playlist)
       playerView.player = player
       player.prepare()
player.play()
```

this creates a blank video with the duration 30000 but nothing is rendered , I have tried multiple images but nothing is rendered,

How can we display image in exoplayer using setImageDurationMs